# How to walk through code blocks under a narrowed subtree?

Tags: org-mode

How to walk through code blocks under a narrowed subtree?

Which function(s) should I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see http://orgmode.org/manual/Key-bindings-and-useful-functions.html#Key-bindings-and-useful-functions

```
C-c C-v p or C-c C-v C-p    org-babel-previous-src-block 
C-c C-v n or C-c C-v C-n    org-babel-next-src-block
```